# Kendo UI Grid Disable Or condition in column filter

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, grid

I have a Kendo UI grid with column filtering enabled, however i want to have only "AND" in the condition for the filter and display/remove the  "OR" condition. Is there any way to do this? I've tried looking around for a solution and so far no luck.

Here is a screen shot of the filter

[image][image]

Comment: please put your code or demo.

Comment: what, have you tried?, please demo

Comment: I've tried the following
`code: filterable: {
    messages : {
        or: ""
    }
}`

this only removes the "Or" text form the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate your DropDownList using the `filterMenuInit` event. Then remove the `or` data.

Check this [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UxiZo)

Comment: Thank you so much! it's exactly what i needed.

Comment: it did not work for me :( 

the filterMenuInit never fired when i clicked on the menu item